# Trying to Write An Auto Answer App to Test iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I'm trying to write an app to auto answer an iphone when there are incoming calls.
The app can be launched by the user and run in the background.

I'm trying to use the IOS Private APIs to do this, but no success.
This is for testing purpose only and won't be submitted to the app store so using private APIs shouldn't be a problem.  The phones aren't jailbroken though.

This is what I have in my AppDelegate.m file (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
id callCenterId = [TUCallCenter sharedInstance];

NSLog(@"callCenterId: %@", callCenterId);

TUCallCenter *object = [[TUCallCenter alloc] init];

NSLog(@"object: %@", object);

[object handleCallModelStateChanged: ^{
    NSLog(@"this is an incoming call");
}];
```

When I run the app, I do see some outputs in the debug panel:

```
2016-02-01 10:32:38.849 AutoAnswer[312:63056] callCenterId: <TUCallCenter: 0x134642b40>
2016-02-01 10:32:38.851 AutoAnswer[312:63056] object: <TUCallCenter: 0x1346496c0>
```

But nothing is shown when I dial the phone when the app is in the foreground.  I can't even get that to work, so forget about making it work in the background.

Any help would be appreciated.